# HTML5 `audio` tag controls disabled for WebRTC audio stream

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc, html5-audio, audio-streaming

In my project I have a WebRTC connection, whose audio stream I direct to the `source` element under the `audio`.

This is how I set it in code:

```js
pc = new RTCPeerConnection(config);

// connect audio / video
pc.addEventListener('track', function (evt) {
    if (evt.track.kind === 'video')
        document.getElementById('video').srcObject = evt.streams[0];
    else
        document.getElementById('audio').srcObject = evt.streams[0];
});
```

And this is my HTML:

```html
<audio controls>
    <source id="audio">
</audio>
```

The audio is playing, but the volume control is disabled.

I tried to control the volume myself, using the `volume` attribute but it didn't change anything…

Is there a way to control audio's volume when it is received from WebRTC audio stream?

Comment: `srcObject` should be set on the media element (`<audio>` or `<video>`), not as a source element.  And, you should use just the video element to play back both the audio and video tracks.

Comment: @Brad Wow, it actually worked. It seems that the `audio` tag is completely unnecessary and I can just use the video.
Thank you for your help 

Comment: Yeah, no problem!